# Power4gear purpose and value

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery, battery-life, asus-laptop

Asus laptops have Power4Gear app installed. Beside usual "custom" settings like when screen dims, laptops goes to sleep etc, does it have any other purpose or value? For example, does this software have some special power or battery management logic which will maybe increase battery life?
On Lenovo laptops I had utility where I could set when battery should start charging, but that settings is not in Power4Gear, nor other advanced stuff I saw on Lenovo.

Answer (score 0):

It's just [bloatware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preinstalled_software).

Windows already has built-in power management features that you can configure in the control panel if you want to.

This app may actually lower your battery life since it's yet another useless app that runs in the background and uses precious memory and CPU resources.